# API from Chargify to retrieve information(count) on users opted for different products

Tags: node.js, chargify

Is there any API provided by chargify to fetch information on the number of users who have opted for the various products handles under  a product family ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, the Chargify API does not provide summary data like counts of subscriptions per product handle.

You can do that kind of analysis in the Business Intelligence tool, and I believe it is possible to get API access to those queries.